# What is the difference between these two tensor notations?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

I'm currently taking a Mathematics course in tensors, as part of my Relativity course.

When using the **Quotient rule** to show that the components of **T** are in fact components of a second-order tensor, I stumble upon a conceptual problem. In the book, "Mathematical Methods for Physicists" by Riley, Hobson, Bence : the authors state that we must contract $$ \ T_{ij} \ \ \ \ \text{with the outer product} \ \ \ \  x_{i}x_{j} $$
And see whether the result is also invariant. If this is true, then it must be true that $T_{ij}$ is invariant.

> The outer product $x_{i}x_{j}$ is a second-order tensor. Contracting this with the $T_{ij}$ given in
> (26.24) we obtain...

Again, I'm new so maybe I am missing the . but what is the difference between $T_{ij}x_{i}x_{j}$ and $T_{ij}x^{i}x^{j}$? I thought the latter is used to contract tensors and "bring down" the indices.

Comment: The former seems like an error. To make sense in Einstein's notation, the former contraction would need Kronecker delta, ie $T_{ij}\delta^{i,i2}\delta^{j,j2}x_{i2}x_{j2}$

Comment: I thought so. Quite confusing.